# Floating dialogs in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create a floating dialog box for my app, without requiring a "Draw over other apps" permission, which will be called when the app is in the background. I've noticed that Whatsapp does something similar allowing you to reply to a message while inside another app, and it doesn't have the "draw over other apps" permission.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Qualified guess, I think this is done with the Notification API.

Comment: I know that the WhatsApp example is done using the notifications, but I was wondering whether or not this was possible without spawning a notification.